# Storing Mixed-Type Range to Array

Tags: arrays, string, vba, text

When storing a range of values to an array with the following logic

```
 dim arr as variant
 arr = range("A1:B20").value
```

Values with Number Formatting as Text and displayed in the cells with a format like "US$22,000,000.00" or "£32,000,000.00" or "C$21,000,000.00" are being stored to the array as a number that is different from the displayed value. (e.g. for the first "US$22,000,000.00" value, the value stored in the array element ends up being something like "879732937329")

I've tried using the following instead to get the displayed text from the cell, however it gives me a type mismatch error when trying to assign a value from the array to another variable (I'm assuming that arr ends up being empty when I use:

```
dim arr as Variant
arr = range("A1:B20").text
```

Is there any way to populate the array with the range's text values without looping and reading each cell to an array element individually?

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that "bird" becomes a string of numbers like "6783"? Do you have actual code and data that you can [edit] into your question so that we can reproduce this issue? As it stands, your assessment defies the very purpose and definition of `Variant`. If you're getting a type mismatch error somewhere down the line, you possibly are treating an empty string as a number, or a cell error as a number. Unqualified `Range` call is implicitly referring to the `ActiveSheet` - is the correct worksheet active when you run the code? Can you change it/refer to a specific sheet?

Comment: Editted question. I realized that normal strings were reproduced okay. However the test described, where numbers are prefixed by currency indicators is still producing this problem. I'll make a sample input + output now.

Comment: @forestaker Can you please edit your post with a screenshot of the immediate window results, similar to what FloLie posted below?

Comment: *numbers are prefixed by currency indicators is still producing this problem* - that's because you are reading the `Text` of the range, instead of its `Value`. `Text` is always going to be a `String` representing the *representation* of the value as it appears in the cells, including any currency indicators. If you mean to store that value in a numeric variable, don't use the `Text` of the cell.

Comment: The problem is elsewhere, as I've tried just reading the range to array and writing the array elements to immediate window and the problem is not there. I am passing this array to other subs within the module so the problem may be arising elsewhere. Will try to continue debugging to locate it. I've marked FloLie's answer as correct.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I want to store the currency indicators to the array. I've noticed however that trying to store the range.text to a variant array does not work at all. I don't believe it stores the range, as I get a type mismatch error when trying to print array elements values to debug

Comment: Again we can't see your code, and you sound pretty confused. If you're storing `Range.Text` then the array contains `Variant/String` items, of course it isn't storing the `Range`. If you want to store ranges, you need to `Set` each array item - storing an object reference, as opposed to a value.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon sorry, in that last comment I meant it wasn't storing the values within the range. "arr = range("anyrangehere").text" doesn't appear to actually store any values to arr.

Also discovered my problem was from not using LookAt:="xlWhole" in a find method that was used to create a dictionary storing column headings. Sorry for the misleading question everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error does not seem to be reproducable. Following code acts as you wish it to:

```
Sub test()
Dim arr As Variant

arr = Range("A1:A6").Value

For Each entry In arr
    Debug.Print entry & vbTab & TypeName(entry)
Next entry


End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Editted question. I realized that normal strings were reproduced okay. However the test described, where numbers are prefixed by currency indicators is still producing this problem. I'll make a sample input + output now.

Comment: I prefer `Dim arr() As Variant`, but it bears no significant difference here. It just makes it more obvious that it is an array of variants instead of an unknown type.